# Firebase_auth - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've gone through all the similar questions but none is similar to my issue.
I have the function below for verifying the OTP sent the mobile number whiles using the verifyPhoneNumber() on the FirebaseAuth instance.

```
Future<User?> manualVerification(code) async { 
  try { 
    await _firebaseAuth .signInWithCredential(
      PhoneAuthProvider.credential( verificationId: _verificationCode, smsCode: code, )) 
      .then((value) async { 
        if (value.user != null) { 
          print("User not null"); 
          print("user ${value.user}"); 
          return value.user; 
        } else { 
          print("User null!");
        } 
      }).catchError((err) { 
        print("manual verification Failed: $err"); return err; }); 
    } catch (e) { 
      print("manualVerification Catch| $e"); 
    } 
  }
```

However, Once the function is called and completes, I get "User not Null" in the console as expected.
But I also get "Null check operator used on a null value" and "type '_CastError' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<User?>'".
Also the function return null for Value.user. But the user is created on the Firebase Console.

I have so far modified the function to this:

```
Future<User?> manualVerification(code) async {
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationCode,
        smsCode: code,
      );
      final authCredential =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

      if (authCredential.user != null) {
        print("Got User");
        print("${authCredential.user!.uid}");
        return authCredential.user;
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print("manualVerification Catch| ${e.message}");
    }
  }
```

And though the function prints the uid of the user I get this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      UserInfo.uid (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:52:24)
#1      UserInfo.toString (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:57:144)
#2      StringBuffer.write (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:64:22)
#3      StringBuffer.writeAll (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:102:7)
#4      IterableBase.iterableToFullString (dart:collection/iterable.dart:267:14)
#5      ListBase.listToString (dart:collection/list.dart:43:20)
#6      List.toString (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:489:33)
#7      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:855:19)
#8      User.toString (package:firebase_auth/src/user.dart:357:5)
#9      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:855:19)
#10     AuthViewModel.verifyPin (package:sxxxxx/ui/auth/auth_viewmodel.dart:81:29)
```

I have tried the same code with firebase_auth: ^1.0.3 and ^1.1.0
I'm on Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

update your firebase auth version.
This solved my issue